# Aggregating an async generator to a tuple

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In trying to aggregate the results from an asynchronous generator, like so:

```
async def result_tuple():
    async def result_generator():
        # some await things happening in here
        yield 1
        yield 2
    return tuple(num async for num in result_generator())
```

I get a

> TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable

when executing the `async for` line.

But [PEP 530](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/#asynchronous-comprehensions) seems to suggest that it should be valid:

> #### Asynchronous Comprehensions
>
> We propose to allow using async for inside list, set and dict comprehensions. Pending PEP 525 approval, we can also allow creation of asynchronous generator expressions.
>
> Examples:
>
> - set comprehension: {i async for i in agen()};
> - list comprehension: [i async for i in agen()];
> - dict comprehension: {i: i ** 2 async for i in agen()};
> - generator expression: (i ** 2 async for i in agen()).

What's going on, and how can I aggregate an asynchronous generator into a single `tuple`?

Answer (score 6):

In the PEP excerpt, the comprehensions are listed side-by-side in the same bullet list, but the generator expression is very different from the others.

There is no such thing as a "`tuple` comprehension". The argument to `tuple()` makes an asynchronous generator:

```
tuple(num async for num in result_generator())
```

The line is equivalent to `tuple(result_generator())`. The tuple then tries to iterate over the generator synchronously and raises the `TypeError`.

The other comprehensions will work, though, as the question expected. So it's possible to generate a tuple by first aggregating to a list, like so:

```
async def result_tuple():
    async def result_generator():
        # some await things happening in here
        yield 1
        yield 2
    return tuple([num async for num in result_generator()])
```